# Returning a bool value using dispatch_async

Tags: iphone, ios, grand-central-dispatch

simple question this time, i've made a "utility" class in my new app which help me to call method in my different UIVIewController.

i use class function to that. But i'm facing a new problem, i have to check if icloud is available or not and i use :

```
+ (BOOL)isIcloudAvailable {

    BOOL isBothIcloudenabled = NO; 

    BOOL isIcloudAvailable = NO;


    NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                   URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    if (ubiq) {
        isIcloudAvailable = YES; 
    } else {
        isIcloudAvailable = NO; 
    }

    NSUserDefaults *aUseriCloud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL boolPref = [aUseriCloud boolForKey:@"icloudEnabled"];

    if (boolPref && isIcloudAvailable)
    {
        isBothIcloudenabled = YES;
    }
    else {
        isBothIcloudenabled = NO;
    }

    return isBothIcloudenabled;

}
```

and on my UIVIewController i use :

```
if ([utils isIcloudAvailable])
{...
}
```

URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil must do be called on the main thread, how can i do that ? I only know dispatch_async but it does not work on a return function.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your UIViewController should be running on the main thread so a dispatch should by unnecessary.  If you're calling a UIViewController method from a different thread, I would recommend you run the invocation of that method using dispatch_async on the main thread, rather than doing it in the method itself.  That is, all method calls in the UIViewController be done on the main thread.

Despite that, blocks can set values outside their scope:

```
bool isCloudAvailable = NO;
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    isCloudAvailable = [utils isIcloudAvailable];
});
```

This will block the thread until the main thread runs the block.

Comment: How 'bout a pony, too? By definition, you can't simultaneously 1) comply with the requirement for calling `URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:` on the main thread, 2) get a *synchronous* answer on a background thread, and 3) not potentially block that background thread.

Comment: If you don't want to be blocked then you need to use futures/promises, or callbacks.  So you will need to dispatch a block to find out if the cloud is available, and when that is done dispatch a call to a block that does the thing you wanted to do if the cloud is available.

Comment: perhaps you can have a race condition with that pony too!  (sorry really bad programmer pun)